# .htaccess hide url param when it exists?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
/login
```

And param:

```
?d=1
```

When param exists I can show additional info on this page, but I need to hide it from url.

And I *can* hide it, but then php thinks that param exists always.

I suppose that the only way is to give away params system and create specific cookie when redirecting to `/login`, and then make `if(isset($_COOKIE['']))` statement in this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a value in your PHP Session, if this is possible:

Before you redirect to the Login page, set a session var:

```
start_session();
$_SESSION['show_id'] = 1;
now_redirect_to_login();
```

On the login page, you then can read the session value:

```
start_session();
$id = $_SESSION['show_id'];
```